# How to remove the green bar on a android app in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, mobile

[image]

Like the title, I am wondering how to get rid of the green bar at the top so that it matches the background of the activity. I have no idea where to look I've had a look in the manifest and haven't found anything.

What do I do so that it matches the background of the activity?

Note. Different activities have different backgrounds, so is there a way that I just match the activity it is on?

Comment: Try to set colorPrimary & colorPrimaryDark for activity theme in style.xml.

Comment: over I want it to change will different activities. Different activities have different backgrounds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The green bar is called Status bar, and to hide it in activity call below method in `onCreate()`

```
void hideStatusBar() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    } else {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
}
```

And to hide it in a fragment, call it in `onCreateView()`

```
void hideStatusBar() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        requireActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    } else {
        requireActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change status bar color using this extension function, call this function from Activity just passing the color

```
fun AppCompatActivity.changeStatusBarColor(@ColorRes color: Int) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, color)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

go to following path:
app->res->values->styles

and here in style tag three item tags are available, in that colour of first and last item keep same.
then app status bar and action bar colour display same.
Example:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here.
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#FFA500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#FFA500</item>

</style>
```